# Modifying standard Codeigniter 2 news tutorial with a delete function

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I am learning Codeigniter 2 and successfully playing around with [their Tutorial/Example about how to create a basic news application](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/index.html).

So after getting this working, I wanted to try to add a "delete record" link to the news item to see if I could figure this out on my own.

I added this to my **models** file, `news_model.php`:

```
public function delete_news($id) {
    $this->db->delete('news', array('id' => $id));
}
```

I added this to my **controllers** file, `news.php`:

```
public function delete($id) {
    $this->news_model->delete_news($id);

    $data['news'] = $this->news_model->get_news();
    $data['title'] = 'News item deleted';

    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('news/index', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

I added this to my **views** file, `index.php`:

```
<a href="/news/delete/<?php echo $news_item['id'] ?>">Delete Item</a>
```

And finally, I added this to my **config** file, `routes.php`

```
$route['news/delete/(:any)'] = 'news/delete/$1';
```

It appears to be working as written.

From the News listing page at `/news/`, I click on the link for the news item and when the page reloads, the corresponding item is gone.

Questions:

1)  After the page reloads, the URL is showing `/news/delete/id`, where `/id` is the item number.  But, I don't want this new URL, I really just want the `/news/` page to reload to show the new content.  Obviously, the way I did this is potentially dangerous, because a simple page refresh by the user would delete another item.  What is the standard way to fix/handle this?

2)  In my Controller `delete()` function, after the first line, I am basically just repeating the same 5 lines of code from the Controller `index()` function.  No doubt this is somehow related to question #1, but again, what is the better way to do this?

3)  Anything else I missed relating to "standard" or "best practice"?

Comment: Just as a note: I’d have a confirmation link, so the article is only deleted on POST. This way, articles aren’t deleted by merely hitting a URL.

Comment: @MartinBean, I totally agree.  Just playing around with the tutorial, but feel free to post an answer and include your suggested improvement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank-you to Jean-François G. B. and Stephan S. for pointing me in the right direction.

This is the working solution...

**controllers** file, `news.php`:

```
public function delete($id) {
    $this->news_model->delete_news($id);
    $this->load->helper('url');
    redirect('/news/');
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

Modified to display a confirmation message, *"record #x deleted"*...

```
public function delete($id) {
    $this->news_model->delete_news($id);
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->session->set_flashdata('error_message', 'record #'. $id . ' deleted');
    redirect('/news/');
}
```

and inside **views** file, `index.php`:

```
<div id="message">
    <?php 
        if ( $this->session->flashdata('error_message') ) {                 
            echo $this->session->flashdata('error_message');
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I'd not include all the stuff again and instead just write:

```
public function delete($id) {
    $this->news_model->delete_news($id);
    redirect(base_url().'news/')
}
```

So after clicking the link and deleting a news the user gets redirected to the normal news page.

See: [CodeIgniter url helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html)

Best Regards

Stephan S.

Comment: Thank-you for your answer.  The `redirect()` throws an error since you did not load the URL helper first.

Comment: Sorry about that! I always "auto-load" the url helper(application/config/autoload.php - helpers) because I need it a lot :) See: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/autoloader.html

Answer (score 1):

1) I suggest you to load the url helper and do a redirect to `/news/` then. If you wish to display a confirmation of deletion, I suggest you to use `flash_message` from the `session` library, it permits to stock an alert in a session until you display it, it's specifically for that purpose.

2) The only better thing you could possibly do might be making an homemade helper to manage your views, so you would only have to call a function with paramaters to output the view. But there is no other way to optimize it or save some lines of code.

3) You did great, it's clean. :)

**EDIT:**

If you need to display a error or success message, please refer to flash_message of the [session library](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html) of CodeIgniter, but here is an example.

Set the error message in your controller, juste before redirecting to the index:

```
$this->load->library('session');
$this->session->set_flashdata('error_message', "This is my error message");
```

And in your index view, you display it if it exists:

```
<?if($this->session->flashdata('error_message')):?>
    <div class="nNote nFailure"><p><?=$this->session->flashdata('error_message');?></p></div>
<?endif;?>
```

Please note that a flash_message is shown once. Which means your index will show your error and then destroy the session message. This is the purpose of flash_message, to correctly and simply show error messages.

Comment: Thank-you for your answer. Actually, the five redundant lines of code in question #2 can be eliminated if I'm doing a redirect to `/news/`.

Comment: Could you expand your answer to explain more about `flash_message` and detail exactly how it could be used here?  Thank-you!

Comment: I can do a redirect, but how to pass the `flash-message` variable to the page?

Comment: You have an equals sign `=` before `$this`.  It still doesn't work.  After deletion, source code of news page shows blank inside the `<p></p>`.

Comment: Found it... you forgot the `echo`.

Comment: Regarding the `=` sign:  [I did not know about this `echo`  shortcut](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php).  However, to even use the `echo` shortcut, `short_open_tag` setting must be enabled or use PHP v 5.40+; and mine was neither.

Answer (score 1):

Next steps would be accounting for errors and bad data

- check $id to make sure its really an integer. this could happen in the controller before calling delete, or as part of the delete method. the important point is that because the id is coming straight from the URL with no validation, you have to do something to check it before letting it near your database.
- in the model, delete_news should return true or false, to confirm that the record was found and deleted.
- in the controller, wrap $this->news_model->delete_news($id); in an IF checking if it came back true from the model, else error redirect.
- if there is an error, since you want the url to change, you can still redirect, just pass an appropriate error code like

redirect('/news/adminerror/delete');

then in your news controller, have a method like adminerror($errortype)
then based on the value of $errortype, which in this case would be a delete error, 
display appropriate message and view.

EDIT

2- in the model, inside your delete method, just put this at the end:

```
if ($this->db->affected_rows() == '1')
{return TRUE;}
else
{return FALSE;}
```

3-  in the controller, wrap in an IF, its usually easier to check if something did not work first

```
if( $this->news_model->delete_news($id) == false )
{ 
// redirect to error page or whatever you need       
} 
// if its not false, then its true, which means it worked
else
{ 
$this->session->set_flashdata('error_message', 'record #'. $id . ' deleted');
redirect('/news/');   
}
```

Final quick tip for update record --

```
$this->db->affected_rows() == '1'
```

is also used to confirm that an update happened. BUT if you do an update, lets say you 
are updating a blog post - and then you click to update again, but actually you didnt change any content.... then this will come back as false. the update did go through, but since the content was the same, the database was not changed or 'affected'.

so if you use that method to confirm an update - there might be a cooler way to do this, but i just send something along with the update content that will always be different - date/time, random number, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  Can you show the code for your first three items?